# Make a copy of an installation

Tags: 7

I am trying to create a copy of a Drupal installation in a different folder.

I want to copy the site that is located on https://my-url/drupal to http://my-url/copy. I copied all the files in the Drupal root to the copy folder and I exported and imported the database in a new database and also changed the database configuration of the copy site using settings.php (copy/sites/default/settings.php).

When I put the main site on maintenance mode though the copy site is also put on maintenance mode.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you check both settings.php file once again.

Comment: hehe...yeap that will work most of times but not this one. The two files are showing a different db as they should. I am breaking my head here.

Comment: Make sure they're not sharing cache bins (memcache/redis/etc)

Comment: Also check that the RewriteBase line in .htaccess file is pointing to the correct directory in each installation.

Comment: @Clive spot on with your suggestion. I will answer this question with the steps I took...thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clive giving me an indication that is something to do with memchache I followed these steps to resolve my issue.

1. Disabled the memcache module.
2. Commented out the memchache configuation settings in the settings.php of the copy site.

This resolves the issue.